# Zend_Gdata_addRecipientToEmailList Error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, google-provisioning-api

I have PHP code that is managing mailing lists using the Provisioning API.  Visitors are able to opt in or out of the mailing list via a web form.  It has been working for ~6 months and stopped working 10/1/2013.

I am using this code for testing:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gapps');
$service = Zend_Gdata_Gapps::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME  ;

$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';
$domain = 'my_domain';
$email = 'test-email@domain.com';
$email_list = 'test-list';

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($username, $password, $service);
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata_Gapps($client, $domain);
$gdata->addRecipientToEmailList($email, $email_list);
```

I'm receiving the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message    'Expected response code 200, got 400
Invalid request URI' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:716\nStack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://apps-ap...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...', NULL)
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(908): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://apps-ap...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...')
#2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(247): Zend_Gdata_App->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_Gapps_EmailListRecipientEntry), 'https://apps-ap...', NULL, NULL, Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(983): Zend_Gdata_Gapps->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_Gapps_EmailListRecipientEntry), 'https://apps-ap...', NULL, NULL, Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(840): Zend_Gdata_App->insertEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_Gapps_EmailListRecipientEntry), 'https://apps-ap...', 'Zend_Gdata_Gapp...')
#5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(1625): Zend_G in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 716
```

Can anyone tell me what happened? And what I need to do to get this working again?

Thanks,
B

Comment: I have the same problem. If it makes you feel better... My guess it something to do with the URL changed server-side. No clue if I can update Zend without breaking our apps though.

Comment: here's the URL in the code it's trying to use: const APPS_BASE_FEED_URI = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds';

Comment: I spent a day and a half confused about what happened.  I am glad that I'm not going crazy.

Comment: Have you looked into the Admin SDK?  I'm trying to get it working to accomplish the same thing but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Google completely remove support for emaillists. Use groups instead lists.

Example:

instead $gdata->addRecipientToEmailList($email, $email_list)

use $gdata->addMemberToGroup($email, $group_name)

deleteEmailList -> deleteGroup

createEmailList -> createGroup

getEmailListRecipientFeed -> retrieveAllMembers

See full syntax in Zend docs: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.gapps.html